# Delete unused documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection which has certain documents which are not used since a very long time. I need to write a query where I want to get these unused document which have not been returned in any of the `find` queries for a long time. Is there any way to do it in MongoDB ?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that. :(  
You have to keep some field in documents to track these kinds of records.

Comment: Do you have any element in document by which you know when this document was used? If no, then... you have no luck.

Comment: I don't have the `lastUsed` field currently in the collection. Thanks anyways @Shrabanee and @Neodan

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by converting your document's `_id` field to `Timestamp` or directly use `$lt` operator on the `_id` field..

```
db.comments.find({_id: {$gt: ObjectId("5272e0f00000000000000000")}})
```

for more info check [this](https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/)

Comment: This answer must be  a comment (-; P.S. `created at timestamp` !== `last usage at timestamp`

Comment: This doesn't help me mate. Not exactly what I am looking for.